# Google Sheets Format a Row depending on the contents of a cell in the row

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, gs-conditional-formatting

I need help with conditional formating.
Essentially the problem is as follows:

If cell 'D3' has text in it that starts with the letters 'BLDUK-ORD' then I need the entire row to turn orange.

Then if cell 'E3' has any text/numbers in it then the entire row needs to turn green.

This will need to be implemented down my entire google sheets document (over 30,000 rows of data currently). Thank you.

Exemplar sheets document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1inkIGMD11AeZ0uTdm60M2G2efu_lPv4Ak3IqGbcyCvU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try on range A3:Z...

green:

```
=($E2<>"")*(REGEXMATCH($D2&"", "^BLDUK-ORD"))
```

orange:

```
=REGEXMATCH($D3&"", "^BLDUK-ORD")
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Maybe it was the way I implemented it?

Comment: @ManrajSandhu can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1inkIGMD11AeZ0uTdm60M2G2efu_lPv4Ak3IqGbcyCvU/edit?usp=sharing